# Random repeated sequence in Javascript

Tags: javascript, matlab

I wrote this Matlab code to generate a vector of random [1 0] and [2 0]:

```
nTrials = 8; 
Seq1 = [1 0]; % sequence 1
Seq2 = [2 0]; % sequence 2

a=repmat(Seq1,(nTrials/4),1); 
b=repmat(Seq2,(nTrials/4),1); 
abcd = vertcat(a,b); % concatenate all three couples
CouplesOrderStruct = abcd(randperm(size(abcd,1)),:); % couples in columns
vector = (reshape(CouplesOrderStruct.',[],1))';
```

The result is a vector like: `[1 0 2 0 2 0 1 0]`

Code explained:

I have two sequences of numbers, 1-0 and 2-0, which I want to randomize in my vector.

1. First, in `a = repmat(Seq1,(nTrials/4),1); b=repmat(Seq2,(nTrials/4),1);` I create a fixed amount of sequences
2. Second, I put a and b together: `abcd = vertcat(a,b); % concatenate all three couples`
3. Third, I randomize these sequences in `CouplesOrderStruct = abcd(randperm(size(abcd,1)),:);`

The results is a vector with the same amount of 1-0 and 2-0, but in a random order

Is there a way to get the same result with JavaScript?

Comment: Okay, so we are not Matlab developers. I appreciate that you gave a Matlab code and you wanna convert it to JavaScript. Can you please also explain what does the Matlab code do? So that we can try helping you with the JavaScript version of it?

Comment: Sure! The Matlab code takes two sequences (1-0 and 2-0), duplicates them for the total number of elements I need (divided by 4 which is 1+0+2+0), and randomizes these sequences within the vector

Comment: Thanks. But the above is still unclear. `:(` Can you please clarify again... `:)`

Comment: I have two sequences of numbers, 1-0 and 2-0, which I want to randomize in my vector.

First, in  a=repmat(Seq1,(nTrials/4),1);  b=repmat(Seq2,(nTrials/4),1); I create a fixed amount of sequences

Second, I put a and b together:  abcd = vertcat(a,b); % concatenate all three couples

Third: I randomize these sequences in  CouplesOrderStruct = abcd(randperm(size(abcd,1)),:); % couples in columns

The results is a vector with the same amount of 1-0 and 2-0, but in a random order

Comment: Awesome... It would be better to [edit] the question and put it step by step in there. I guess I can solve it. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooo i just built a nice tiny documented function for you:

```
function randomRepeatSequence(sequences, times) {
    // times has to be a multiple of sequences.length
    if (times % sequences.length !== 0)
        return console.log("times has to be a multiple of sequences.length");

    // Remap our sequence-array so we can store the count it has been used
    var seqmap = [];
    for (var seqid = 0; seqid < sequences.length; seqid++)
        // Push the current sequence n times; n = times/sequences.length
        for (var idx = 0; idx < times/sequences.length; idx++)
            seqmap.push(sequences[seqid]);

    var resultmap = [];
    // Now just select and remove a random sequence from our seqmap, until it is empty
    while (!seqmap.length == 0) {
        // Select a random element
        var randomidx = Math.floor(Math.random()*seqmap.length);
        var currentElement = seqmap[randomidx];
        // remove the random element from seqmap...
        seqmap.splice(randomidx, 1);
        // .. and push it to the resultmap
        resultmap.push(currentElement);
    }

    // now our resultmap looks like [[1],[2],[3]]... just flatten it!
    var result = resultmap.reduce( function(a, b) {
        return a.concat(b);
    });

    return result;      
}
```

You can use it just like

```
console.log(randomRepeatSequence([[1,0], [2,0]], 4));
```

Or, better to understand:

```
var seqlist = [
    [1, 0],
    [2, 0]
]
randomRepeatSequence(seqlist, 4)
```

Please care, the `times` parameter just takes the amount of sequences that have to be used, not the length of the result. But you just have to calculate that in a easy step like

```
randomRepeatSequence(seqlist, 8/seqlist[0].length)
```

(giving 4, because seqlist[0].length = 2 and 8 / 2 is 4)

---

**Original Answer**

Your result is for example

```
vector = 2 0 1 0 2 0 1 0
```

I guess seq1 and seq2 should be contained equal times.
I decided to use an easy-to-understand-approach, even through I can do shorter:

```
var trials = 8; // has to be even

var seq1 = [1, 0];
var seq2 = [2, 0];

// "Build" a sequence list
var seqlist = [
    seq1, seq1,
    seq2, seq2
]

var list = []

for (var n = 0; n < trials/2; n++) {
    // search a random entry
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*seqlist.length);
    var toUseSeq = seqlist[index];

    // delete the entry
    seqlist.splice(index, 1);

    list.push(toUseSeq);
}
// flatten result array

var result = list.reduce( function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
});

console.log(result);
```

Executing this gaves me one of these console outputs:

```
[ 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0 ] 
[ 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0 ]
[ 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0 ]
[ 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0 ]
```