# Repeated sequence of numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, matlab

I want to generate a vector of 100 values composed by [1 0]:
This is how I did it in Matlab:

```
 n = 100; 
 Seq1 = [1 0]; % sequence of 1-0
 Vector = repmat(Seq1,(n/2),1); % Creates n/2 sequences of 1-0
```

The result is a vector like: [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0...]

Is there a way to get the same result with JavaScript?

Comment: Why did you ask the same question again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random repeated sequence in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685714/random-repeated-sequence-in-javascript)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, this is about one single sequence, not two. And there is no randomization involved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for a way to add a 1 and then a 0, not an array containing 1 and 0:

```
var myArray = [];
nTrials = 30;
for(i = 1; i<= nTrials/2; i++){
  myArray.push(1);
  myArray.push(0)
}
document.body.innerHTML = myArray[1];}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6seqs6af/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could mimic the function `repmat` with a while loop.

```js
function repmat(array, count) {
    var result = [];
    while (count--) {
        result = result.concat(array);
    }
    return result;
}

var nTrials = 100,
    Seq1 = [1, 0],
    Vector = repmat(Seq1, nTrials / 2); 

console.log(Vector);
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here is the full `repmat` implementation in JavaScript.

It uses arrow functions (`=>`) which isn't available in all browsers.

```js
 // Seq1 is an Array (1D vector). We need a Matrix which JavaScript doesn't have
 // natively. But we can derive a Matrix type from an Array by adding 
 // `numberOfRows` and `numberOfColumns` properties as well as a `set` method 

 function Matrix(numberOfRows, numberOfColumns) {
   this.numberOfColumns = numberOfColumns;
   this.numberOfRows = numberOfRows;
   this.length = numberOfColumns * numberOfRows;
   this.fill();
 }

 Matrix.prototype = Array.prototype;

 Matrix.prototype.set = function() {
   for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
     this[i] = arguments[i];
   }
   return this;
 }

 Matrix.prototype.toString = function() {
   return this.reduce((acc, x, idx) => acc + (idx % this.numberOfColumns === this.numberOfColumns - 1 ? x + '\n' : x + ', '), '');
 }

 Matrix.prototype.at = function(row, column) {
   return this[row * this.numberOfColumns + column];
 }

 // Repmap
 // ======

 function repmat(mat, repeatColumns, repeatRows) {
   var numberOfColumns = mat.numberOfColumns * repeatColumns;
   var numberOfRows = mat.numberOfRows * repeatRows;

   var values = [];
   for (var y = 0; y < numberOfRows; y++) {
     for (var x = 0; x < numberOfColumns; x++) {
       values.push(mat.at(y % mat.numberOfRows, x % mat.numberOfColumns));
     }
   }

   var result = new Matrix(numberOfRows, numberOfColumns);
   result.set.apply(result, values);

   return result;
 }

 // Calculation
 // ===========

 var nTrials = 100;

 var seq1 = new Matrix(1, 2);
 seq1.set(1, 0);

 var vector = repmat(seq1, nTrials / 2, 1);

 console.log(vector.toString());
```